# Cannot find name 'Buffer' error in Angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I was working through on my application and this error message started occurring and I have no idea why. Everything was working fine and I'm not sure what I could've changed to cause these errors to occur. I have tried to install @types/node and added

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "types" : ["node"]
 }
```

to my tsconfig.json, but that doesn't work.

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/file_system/src/types.d.ts:37:43 - error 
TS2591: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i 
@types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.

37     readFileBuffer(path: AbsoluteFsPath): Buffer;
node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/file_system/src/types.d.ts:38:52 - error TS2591: Cannot 
find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i @types/node` and 
then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.

38     writeFile(path: AbsoluteFsPath, data: string | Buffer, exclusive?: boolean): void;                                                      
node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/file_system/src/node_js_file_system.d.ts:10:43 - error 
TS2591: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i 
@types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.

10     readFileBuffer(path: AbsoluteFsPath): Buffer;                                             
node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/file_system/src/node_js_file_system.d.ts:11:52 - error 
TS2591: Cannot find name 'Buffer'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i 
@types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.

11     writeFile(path: AbsoluteFsPath, data: string | Buffer, exclusive?: boolean): void;
```

I'm really stumped on this. Any ideas to fixing this issue?

Comment: Maybe just delete node_modules and run npm i..?

Comment: I tried this and unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: any solutions? got same